# $2$-dim positively curved Alexandrov space

Tags: metric-geometry

A statement in the book I am reading states that any $2$-dimensional positively curved closed Alexandrov space is homeomorphic to $S^2$ or $\mathbb RP^2$. Is there any reference for this fact?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223479/classification-of-2-dimensional-alexandrov-spaces may be helpful.